# How to append all answer to 1 array

Tags: python, arrays

How to append all answer from for loop into an array

I tried:

```
for k in range(n):
    a = 1/ (2*k+1) 
    print(a)
    a.append = array[]

i expect the answer 
1.0
0.3333333333333333
0.2
0.14285714285714285
0.1111111111111111
0.09090909090909091
0.07692307692307693
0.06666666666666667
0.058823529411764705
0.05263157894736842
```

to be : `[1.0,0.3333333333333333,0.2,......,0.05263157894736842]`

Comment: That's a list, not an array

Comment: Srome may have come from a different programming language where they are called arrays. (Like Java or C++)

Though @MadPhysicist is correct that in Python it's called a list, which is always dynamically sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = []   
for k in range(n):
        a = 1/ (2*k+1) 
        print(a)
        array.append(a)
```

Should do the trick and stays close to your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Try List Comprehension:

```
n = 10
print ([1.0/(2*k+1) for k in range(n)])
```

**Output:**

```
[1.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.2, 0.14285714285714285, 0.1111111111111111, 0.09090909090909091, 0.07692307692307693, 0.06666666666666667, 0.058823529411764705, 0.05263157894736842]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you were close :

```
arr = []
for k in range(n):
   a = 1/ (2*k+1) 
   print(a)
   arr.append(a)
```